# C# Find and show html element in webBrowser

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have this html document:

```
<div class="link1">
<a href="#">link1</a>
</div>

<div class="link2">
<a href="#">link2</a>
</div>

<div class="link3">
<a href="#">link3</a>
</div>

<div class="link3">
<a href="#">link4</a>
</div>

<div class="link5">
<a href="#">link4</a>
</div>
```

I want to show elements that specified with "link3" in webBrowser control by getting element by class name.

This code works, but if we have two elements by same class name it show nothing!

```
        foreach (HtmlElement elm in webBrowser1.Document.All)
        if (elm.GetAttribute("className") == "link3")
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            doc.Body.InnerHtml = elm.InnerHtml;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlElement elm in webBrowser1.Document.All)
    if (elm.GetAttribute("className") == "link3")
        sb.Append(elm.InnerHtml);
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
doc.Body.InnerHtml=sb.ToString();
```